# SwiftUI NavigationButton without the disclosure indicator?

Tags: swiftui

When making a List with a row that pushes to a new view, SwiftUI adds a disclosure indicator ">" automatically? How do I remove it if I don't want it?

```
    NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationButton(destination: DetailView()) {
                ListItem()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Some title"))
    }
```

On a UITableViewCell you set Accessory to None but how do I do that in SwiftUI?

Comment: Take it out of the list and put it in a ForEach. Then embed this in a ScrollView.  If you have text, you will have to set the foreground color back to .primary or whatever color you wish.

Comment: A solution for iOS 16: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74198140/7653367

Answer (score 51):

Setting the NavigationLink width and hiding it did the trick for me

```
List {
  ForEach(pages) { page in
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
      Text("Something")

      NavigationLink(destination: Text("Somewhere")) {
        EmptyView()
      }
      .frame(width: 0)
      .opacity(0)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It Is working, but is showing a small white screen before transitioning to the other view.

Comment: this adds extra spacing unless put into ZStack

Comment: @IvanKvyatkovskiy The small space is because HStack has non-0 spacing by default. If you change the top `HStack` to `HStack(spacing: 0)` then it will work.

Answer (score 29):

Swift 5, Xcode 11. ZStack works perfect.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.currenciesViewModel) { cellViewModel in
                ZStack {
                    cellViewModel.makeView()
                    NavigationLink(destination: ChooseCurrencyListView()) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work with `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())`.

Comment: This works perfectly in Xcode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300) Preview, but doesn't work at all in Version 12.0.1 (940.16) Simulator.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest one. The content for each item in the list.

```
ZStack {
   NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
       EmptyView()
   }.hidden()
   RowView()
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this only works on visible views/cells in a list. As soon as I scroll to a view/cell that is out of the screen, the navigationLink stops working, but will work on the views/cells that were initially visible.

Comment: Worked great for me but I had to remove the .hidden(), which should not be a problem since the navigation view is an EmptyView.

Answer (score 18):

You can also put it in the `.background` modifier:

```
List {
    Text("Go to...")
        .background(NavigationLink("", destination: Text("Detail View")))
}
```

If you already have the `background` modifier on the Text, you can wrap the Text in a HStack and apply `background` to the HStack.

Comment: I found the indicator is still shown, `.opacity(0.0)` is need to hide the indicator

Answer (score 13):

As workaround I can suggest to add .padding modifier like this:

```
NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationButton(destination: DetailView()) {
                ListItem()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Some title"))
    }
    .padding(.trailing, -32.0)
```

So you will get rows without visible disclosure:

[image: Result]

Comment: This doesn't respect accessibility and automation, it is still there just "some" people can't see it.

Answer (score 8):

What you can do, if you are using list, is setting the navigationlink to hidden and its frame width to zero.

```
    HStack{
            Button(action: {self.statusShow = 1}, label: {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle")
            })
            NavigationLink(destination: StimulatorSettingView(),
                           tag: 1,
                           selection: self.$statusShow){
                            EmptyView()

            }.hidden().frame(width: 0)
        }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

As of beta 6, this works well:

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {   
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Text("My Cell Content")
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("destination"), label: {
                        EmptyView()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also use a VStack so the Text (or any other view) will take up the entire width of the List.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to use `NavigationLink` to wrap your `Label` directly.  It will work as long as the link is anywhere in your view hierarchy.

Here I've wrapped it in a button, which allows you to trigger an action prior to pushing the view.  Since the `NavigationLink` has an `EmptyView` for the label the disclosure indicator is not visible.  You can also style this with `ButtonStyle`.

```swift
struct NavigationButton<Destination: View, Label: View>: View {
    var action: () -> Void = { }
    var destination: () -> Destination
    var label: () -> Label

    @State private var isActive: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.action()
            self.isActive.toggle()
        }) {
            self.label()
              .background(NavigationLink(destination: self.destination(), isActive: self.$isActive) {
                  EmptyView() 
               })
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```swift
NavigationButton(
    action: { print("tapped!") },
    destination: { Text("Pushed View") },
    label: { Text("Tap me") }
  )
```

Comment: Tried this on ios 14.5 but unfortunately the disclosure indicator still shows up

Answer (score 4):

`NavigationLink` is what we should define in a scope enclosed inside a `NavigationView`.
But when we use `NavigationLink` it is attached to the enclosing view, so to reuse the same `NavigationLink` with other views, we use `tag` which differentiates between different **Destinations**.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
@State private var viewState: Int? = 0

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("View 1"), tag: 1, selection: $viewState) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }

                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("View 2"), tag: 2, selection: $viewState) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }

                    Text("First View")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.viewState = 1
                        }

                    Text("Second View")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.viewState = 2
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Here we bind a `Hashable` property with all the `NavigationLinks` present in our `VStack` so that when a particular View is tapped we can notify which **Destination** should be opened by setting the value of `Bindable` property.
If we don't notify the correct **Destination** by setting the value of `tag`, always the View defined inside the Closure of `NavigationLink` will be clickable and nothing else.

Using this approach you don't need to wrap all your clickable views inside `NavigationView`, any action on any view can use any `NavigationLink` just by setting the `tag`.

Thanks, hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Works well for me!

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(["iPhone SE", "iPhone 11 Pro Max"], id: \.self) { deviceName in
            LandmarkList()
                .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
                .previewDisplayName(deviceName)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `.frame(width: 0).opacity(0.0)`:

```
NavigationView {
  List {
    ForEach(options) {
      option in
        ZStack {
          YourView(option: option)
          NavigationLink(destination: ProductListView(),
            label: {
              EmptyView()
            }).frame(width: 0).opacity(0.0)
        }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    }
  }.navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My version of this solution is to make a view modifier. I think it's the cleanest way, as it doesn't use AnyView.

Note that this solution runs the init() for the destination when it draws the element the .navigationLink() is attached to.

#### Usage

```
Text("Link")
  .navigationLink({ 
    // put your destination here
  })
```

#### How To

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
  func navigationLink<Destination: View>(_ destination: @escaping () -> Destination) -> some View {
    modifier(NavigationLinkModifier(destination: destination))
  }
}

fileprivate struct NavigationLinkModifier<Destination: View>: ViewModifier {

  @ViewBuilder var destination: () -> Destination

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .background(
        NavigationLink(destination: self.destination) { EmptyView() }.opacity(0)
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reusable "plain" navigation link view (i.e. without the chevron disclosure indicator) that can be a drop-in replacement for `NavigationLink`:

```
struct PlainNavigationLink<Label, Destination>: View where Label: View, Destination: View {
    @ViewBuilder var destination: () -> Destination
    @ViewBuilder var label: () -> Label

    var body: some View {
        label()
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: destination, label: {})
                    .opacity(0)
            )
    }
}
```

To use it, simply replace `NavigationLink` with `PlainNavigationLink`:

```
NavigationView { // or NavigationStack in iOS 16
    List {
        ForEach(1...30, id: \.self) { _ in
            PlainNavigationLink {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            } label: {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can also extend it with convenience initializers for `LocalizedStringKey` and `String`, just like `NavigationLink` does.

Answer (score 1):

This helps to push and pass the model to the next navigation view controller.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var model = PostListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(model.post) { post in
                ListCell(listData: post)
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("My Post"))
        }
    }

}

struct ListCell: View {
    var listData: Post
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationButton(destination: DetailContentView(post: listData)) {
            HStack {
                ImageRow(model: listData) // Get image
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(listData.login).font(.headline).lineLimit(nil)
                    Text(listData.url).font(.subheadline).lineLimit(nil)
                    }.padding(.leading, 10)
                }.padding(.init(top: 5, leading: 0, bottom: 5, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just came here looking for the answer to this question, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me (can't have an empty view, because i want to put something in the list row; i'm already messing with the padding (and increasing trailing padding didn't seem to work) ...  i was about to give up, and then something occurred to me: what if you crank up the z-index of the list row itself?  seemed somewhat unlikely, but i gave it a try and, i'll be damned, it worked!  i was so pleasantly surprised, i felt like sharing ...

e.g.:

```
// in body of your list row view
HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0.0) {
    // stuff ...
}
.zIndex(9999999999)
```

Comment: This does work, although `zIndex(.infinity)` is a bit more elegant than 999999

Answer (score 0):

If you need children behaviour for List and NavigationLink, without additional discloser in the same time, I want to promote this tricky solution, main point at **HStack**

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(items, children: \.items) { item in
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView()) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.hidden()
                HStack {
                    RowView(item: item)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But doesn't the `.hidden()` disable the ability to tap to navigate to `Detailsview()`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ZStack
2. add an Empty view in the Navigation Link
3. Set the opacity to zero

Code Sample:

> ```
> ZStack (alignment: .leading) {
>        NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView()) {
>            EmptyView()
>         }
>         .opacity(0.0)
>         RowCell()
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Once you put your button in a scrollview, the disclosure button will be hidden. Just make sure to disable your scroll indicator.

Answer (score -3):

there is no documentation yet, so you can use **ScrollView** for now

```
  NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0...100){ x in
                NavigationButton(destination: Text("ss")) {
                    HStack {
                          Text(String(x))
                          Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .shadow(radius:1,y:1)
                }
             }
             .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32)
             .padding()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Removing `List` and just using `ForEach` works fine with navigation link. You just have to create your own list row. This works for me

```swift
NavigationView {
   ForEach(pages) {
    page in
      NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
         ListItem()
     }
   }
}
```