# How Can I Wrap Text in a SwiftUI NavigationButton?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI's `Text` type has a modifier that allows text to wrap if the text is too long to fit horizontally within its container. To achieve text wrapping, simply pass `nil` as the argument to the `lineLimit` modifier:

```swift
Text("This text is too long to fit horizontally within its non-NavigationButton container. Therefore, it should wrap to fit, and it does.")
    .font(.body)
    .lineLimit(nil)
```

The above works as expected, except for when used inside of a SwiftUI `NavigationButton`. All `Text` instances that I have nested within `NavigationButton` instances do not wrap:

```swift
NavigationButton(destination: DestinationView()) {
    Text("This text is too long to fit horizontally within its NavigationButton container. Therefore, it should wrap to fit, but it does not.")
        .font(.body)
        .lineLimit(nil)
}
```

Is there anything that I am missing from the code above that would allow `Text` instances to wrap within `NavigationButton` instances?

**Edit to add more context:**

The initial view is a `List` that is wrapped in a `NavigationView`. The `List` contains instances of `MeasurableItemsListItem`, which are wrapped in `NavigationButton` instances that trigger navigation to a secondary view that is added to the navigation stack:

```swift
struct MeasurableItemsList : View {

    private let measurableItems = MeasurableItem.allCases

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(measurableItems.identified(by: \.self)) { measurableItem in
                NavigationButton(destination: DosableFormsList(measurableItem: measurableItem)) {
                    MeasurableItemsListItem(measurableItem: measurableItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each list item that is wrapped in a `NavigationButton` is made from the following structure:

```swift
struct MeasurableItemsListItem : View {

    let measurableItem: MeasurableItem

    var body: some View {
        Text(measurableItem.name)
            .font(.body)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .lineLimit(nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Nick can you give us some context? did you add the NavigationButton inside a row of List? or inside a Stack?

Comment: Hi, @GiuseppeSapienza. I have provided an edit to give additional context about the configuration of my views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be helped with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56604599/30602

The summary is that inside other Builders you need to add `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` to your Text() to get it to wrap.

Comment: That solved it! I vaguely recall seeing that modifier before, and I’m not sure why it didn’t cross my mind in this situation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `NavigationButton` to achieve navigation. You can achieve it by using `NavigationLink` easily, wherein you don't need to wrap your views inside `NavigationButton`.
Check [this ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57346677/7603313) which is explaining the usage of `NavigationLink` without wrapping view inside it. I hope it helps.
P.S.- i don't have enough reputation points to add this as a comment. Thanks