# SwiftUI - NavigationView Adds Detail Indicator ">" to List View - How to remove?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using a NavigationView to link to a Detail View from a List, SwiftUI automatically adds a `>` detail/disclosure indicator to the right side of the List view row. The `>` and the padding around it are causing issues with my layout which I would like to extend all the way to the end of the row. How can I remove the disclosure indicator?

The same question was asked here [SwiftUI NavigationButton without the disclosure indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516333/swiftui-navigationbutton-without-the-disclosure-indicator) but at the time, there was no solution, only work arounds that don't work so well.

Is there a solution to this problem yet, or is it a matter of waiting for SwiftUI to be updated?

Screenshot of the Issue:

[image]

Comment: We have to wait. There isn't yet a "real" solution with List.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwiftUI NavigationButton without the disclosure indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516333/swiftui-navigationbutton-without-the-disclosure-indicator)

Comment: I updated the duplicate question with a new answer that works with beta 6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57636908/7786555

Comment: @kontiki: Thanks, that's an interesting workaround. It'll work for now!

Comment: UPDATE: I'm now using a ZStack as suggested in this answer and it seems to be working a bit better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58426294/11925891. I will note that I had to remove the .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) as my code would not compile with it. No idea why, but hey, that's SwiftUI right now!

Answer (score 1):

iOS13 , iOS 14

```swift
List { 
    ForEach(items) { item in
        ZStack {
            CustomView(item: item)
            NavigationLink(destination: anotherView()) {
                EmptyView()
            }
              .opacity(0)
              .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```