# SwiftUI NavigationLink Hide Arrow

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

Is there a way to hide the arrow to the right of the navigation link view that is automatically added?

I want to show an image grid using NavigationView -> List -> HStack -> NavigationLink_1 - NavigationLink_2

The NavigationLinks have arrows and it looks weird
[image]

Comment: also curious about this, did you find an answer?

Comment: @crazyhor77 nah, I went back to storyboard, UICollectionView, and segues on cell clicks after this.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516333/swiftui-navigationbutton-without-the-disclosure-indicator

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The way it worked for me:

```
List { 
    ForEach(elements) { element in
        ZStack {
            CustomView(element: element)
            NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
                EmptyView()
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used `Rectangle().opacity(0.0)` instead of `EmptyView()` for List, it worked.

Comment: I'm using the same solution but the problem is that even though the arrow is not visible, you can still tap it. In my application I have to disable this otherwise it will crash. Any ideas?

Comment: .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) is working for me.

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS14.2+

Answer (score 59):

The easiest way I've found is to place the navigation in the `.background` modifier with the `opacity` of zero:

```swift
List {
    Text("The cell")
        .background(
            NavigationLink("", destination: Text("The detail view"))
                .opacity(0)
        )
}
```

And with this solution you don't loose the dynamic height functionality of the cells.

**Bonus:** Using `.overlay` modifier works too!

Comment: The only working answer I've found. Thanks !

Comment: Still works with iOS 15

Comment: Still works with iOS 16

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (no offense)

Comment: Still works with iOS 17

Comment: This worked on Xcode 15.2 beta

Answer (score 24):

I got it done with this

```
NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
      EmptyView()
}
.frame(width: 0, height: 0)
.hidden()
```

Comment: .hidden() should be enough

Comment: I had to include the frame along with hidden because it caused a Text to truncate its contents when the NavigationLink was to the right of the Text in a List row if I just wrote hidden without the zero-size frame, so at least in my case I needed to write it as the answer above says.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that helped me is to add `.opacity(0)` to NavigationLink like so:

```
List { 
    ForEach(elements) { element in
        ZStack {
            CustomView(element: element)
            NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()), 
            label: {}).opacity(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
List { 
    ForEach(elements) { element in
        ZStack {
            CustomView(element: element)
            NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
                EmptyView()
            }.opacity(0.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've also struggled with this recently and I think I've found a solution by using a custom view for the navigation link (it works for me):

```
struct CustomNavigationLink<D: View, L: View>: View {
  @ViewBuilder var destination: () -> D
  @ViewBuilder var label: () -> L
  
  @State private var isActive = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      withAnimation {
        isActive = true
      }
    } label: {
      label()
    }
    .onAppear {
      isActive = false
    }
    .overlay {
      NavigationLink(isActive: $isActive) {
        destination()
      } label: {
        EmptyView()
      }
      .opacity(0)
    }
  }
}
```

And you use like this:

```
CustomNavigationLink {
  SomeViewHere()
} label: {
  Text("hello world")
}
```

Comment: Very clean solution. Also works without the isActive part I think

Answer (score 4):

Finally found out a way how to avoid the the chevron without doing some tricky `ZStacks` and other solutions. The only downside is that this is only tested on **iOS 16** with the new `NavigationPath` + `NavigationStack`.

Instead of using a regular `NavigationLink` where you apply the `hashable` object, you'll just use a regular `Button` and append the object to the `NavigationPath`.

### Example:

```
@State private var path = NavigationPath()

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(viewModel.customers) { customer in
            Button {
                path.append(customer)
            } label: {
                CustomerCell(customer: customer)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: Customer.self) { customer in
        CustomerView(customer: customer)
    }
}
```

For projects using the [NavigationBackport](https://github.com/johnpatrickmorgan/NavigationBackport) (for preparing the new navigation), it might work as well. As you can use `NBNavigationPath` and append the object to the path with a `Button` just like the example above.

Answer (score 3):

```
@State var selection: Int? = nil

var body: some View {
    let navigation = NavigationLink(destination: Text("View"), tag: 1, selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
    return 
        VStack { 
            navigation
            Text("Tap").onTapGesture { self.selection = 1 }
        }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work as when you go back it's not possible to select the same element.

Comment: I used navigationlink in this way and everything worked fine.

Comment: This doesn't work when using a `Form`:

`
var body: some View {
    Form {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("View"), tag: 1, selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
        Text("Tap").onTapGesture { self.selection = 1 }
    }
}
`

NOTE: the `VStack` in the above example isn't needed.

Comment: Try in this way: VStack { navlink Form}

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me, just adding an empty `NavigationLink` in a `ZStack`

```
List(viewModel.items, id: \.id) { item in
    ZStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: Destination()) {}
        CustomView(item: item)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I still see the arrow on the right.

Comment: This is the one I selected and it works great for me. But I'm sad we still have to hack this.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `.opacity(0)` on the `NavigationLink` seems to be the most reliable solution for me because I noticed that it might show the indicators again when messing with the `.listStyle` property. You will also not lose the highlighted effect.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    .opacity(0)

                    Text(item.value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only this worked for me, when I tried to implement button tap inside row in List:

```
ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: FlightBoardInformation(flight: flight), tag: FlightBoardNavigation.toFlightDetailed, selection: $navigation) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .hidden()
                .disabled(true)
                Button(action: {
                        self.navigation = .toFlightDetailed
                }) {
                    Text("\(self.flight.airline) \(self.flight.number)")
                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `.background(...).opacity(0)` works, in a more complex view it expands itself through all the view and conflicts with other elements like buttons.

If you need it inside a `List`, what worked for me is also marking the `NavigationLink` as `.disabled(true)`:

```
    Text(...)
      .background( NavigationLink(...).opacity(0).disabled(true) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.background` modifier.

```swift
ForEach(elements) { e in
  AnyViewYouWantToShow(e)
    .background(
      NavigationLink("", destination: DestinationView()))
        .opacity(0)
    )
}
```

Comment: This worked for me iOS 15. Just make sure to use the EmptyView() call

Answer (score 1):

**2023 Update**

This simple solution works for me:

```swift
ZStack {
    CustomCell()  
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
     EmptyView()
    }
    .opacity(0)
}
```

Comment: Works in my case, using a NavigationStack, when none of the other answers did.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround for me is using `background`:

```swift
NavigationLink(...) {}
       .opacity(0)
       .background(
         HStack {
           Text("Your custom view without arrow")
         }
       )
```

Or if you need dynamic height as @turingtested posted use NavigationLink as background

```
Text("Your custom view without arrow")
        .background(NavigationLink( ... ) {}.opacity(0))
```

Comment: Switching the hierarchy (i.e. placing the `NavigationLink` in the background of your `HStack`), per the explanation by @turingtested, is better.

Answer (score 0):

though there is lots of solution. I'm posting my one.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        List{
            ForEach (items){item in
                switch item.onClick {
                    //For SettingsOverviewView
                case .Settings:
                    ZStack{
                        NavigationLink (destination: SettingsMenuView(item: item)){
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                        .opacity(0.0)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        
                        //some views that you will show as your listItem
                        HStack {
                           Text(item.name)
                              .font(.body)
                           Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of examples playing around with `ZStack` and `.opacity` but for my opinion SwiftUI can offer more elegant solution using `NavigationLink` with `isActive` parameter that works perfect with `.listRowSeparator` or `.listStyle` modificators:

```
struct HidingNavArrowInList: View {
    
    let planets = ["Mars", "Sun", "Mercury", "Venus", "Jupiter", "Uranus", "Saturn", "Earth"]
    
    @State var selectedPlanet: String?
    @State var showDetailView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(planets, id: \.self) { planet in
                    Text(planet)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            segue(planet: planet)
                        }
                }
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(isActive: $showDetailView, destination: {
                    if let unwrappedPlanet = selectedPlanet {
                        VStack {
                            Text("This is detail view of \(unwrappedPlanet)")
                        }
                    }
                }, label: {
                    EmptyView()
                })
            )
        }
    }
    
    private func segue(planet: String) {
        selectedPlanet = planet
        showDetailView.toggle()
    }
}
```

Comment: `'init(isActive:destination:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView`
Deprecated for iOS 16

Answer (score 0):

In my case, foregroundColor modifier works for me.

```
NavigationLink(EmptyView(), label: {
//place your custom view
    Text("your Label")
}).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).foregroundColor(Color.clear)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do like:
This worked for me,

```
@State var boolValue: Bool = false


                HStack {
                    Text("Your text")
                    Toggle(isOn: $boolValue){
                        Text("")
                    }
                    if boolValue {
                        NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }.frame(width: 0)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

It also works with any View (not only Text)

```
ZStack {
    Text("Some text")
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello")) { 
            EmptyView()
    }.frame(width: 0)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I set the `opacity` of the `navigationLink` to zero and it work like a charm

```swift
NavigationLink(
    destination: Text("Destination"),
    label: {}
).opacity(0)
```